# Add MouseClick Event on ScrollPane in JavaFX

Tags: events, javafx, scrollpane, onmouseclick

I have created a Scroll Pane (with Anchor Pane) in JavaFX.
On runtime I am creating a rectangle and adding it to the ScrollPane.
I want to add a mouse click event on the scroll pane, in which I can change the contents of the scrollPane on runtime.

I tried doing that but I get this exception when I click on the ScrollPane

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$7900(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my JavaFX fxml part,

```
<ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" layoutX="229.0" layoutY="183.0" onMouseClicked="#ChangeImageColor" prefHeight="137.0" prefWidth="143.0">
       <content>
           <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="154.0" prefWidth="157.0" />
       </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

And My Java Code,

```
@FXML
void ChangeImageColor(ActionEvent event)
{
    System.out.print("Hit!");
    scrollPane.setContent(null);
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(200, 200, Color.BLUEVIOLET);
    rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    rectangle.setStrokeWidth(25);
    scrollPane.setContent(rectangle);           
}
```

This is what i am doing on initialization,

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(200, 200, Color.RED);
rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
rectangle.setStrokeWidth(25);
scrollPane.setContent(rectangle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because of the declaration of the method

```
@FXML    
void ChangeImageColor(ActionEvent event)
```

Here the parameter should be of type `MouseEvent` instead of `ActionEvent`. You can also remove the parameter if you are not sure of the kind of event it is. Try using :

```
@FXML    
void ChangeImageColor()
```

or

```
@FXML    
void ChangeImageColor(MouseEvent event)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why did adding the event in the fxml did not work.
I simply added the event definition in the Java code and it worked perfectly fine.

```
scrollPane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() 
{
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event)
    {
         //Logic on event occurrence
    }
});
```